# What kind of circuitry to be used?

Tags: transducer

A pressure transducer device is outputting 0 to 5V range voltage. So when the applied pressure is negative it is still zero. The device can only output positive voltage.

This same device output can be arranged such that the output can be 0 to 5V when applied "negative pressure" and zero for any positive pressure.
And finally it can also be adjusted from range 0 to 2.5V to 5V where 2.5V represents zero pressure and 0 to 2.5V represents negative pressure and 2.5V to 5V represents positive pressure.

What kind of circuit elements would be needed to achieve such functionality?

The device has no schema that's why I just wondered.

Comment: Pressure transducers can be readily bought; you could then condition the output signal to your needs. Are you trying to make everything?

Comment: You're asking us to reverse-engineer an existing device with no more information than that? We could speculate, but that would be useless. You need to open the device up an see what the circuit looks like. Identify components, draw a schematic, then come back here if there are still points you don't understand.

Comment: comparators and opams?

Comment: -1 for a poor title. Given this is an electronics site, that title doesnt do anything to distinguish the question from any other.

Comment: how long u want the title to be ? there isnt enough space to explain with a title.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a pressure transducer that would typically consist of a resistive [bridge](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wheatstone_bridge) powered from a single voltage that outputs a small differential signal (perhaps 50mV full scale). If the bridge is energized with (say) 4.0V, then the two outputs would be around 2V and the difference would change from +50mV to -50mV depending on the pressure differential (this is assuming it's a gauge-pressure type sensor with one side vented to the atmosphere and the other connected to an inlet tube-- absolute sensors have a vacuum reference on one side, and differential sensors have an inlet on each side). See the below [typical diagram](http://www.planetanalog.com/document.asp?doc_id=527950).

[image]

The three op-amp configuration is called an "instrumentation amplifier. In this case, the output voltage is shown as going to an ADC, but in your case, the Vin would be buffered and fed to the output.

Now, if you note the Voff connection to the instrumentation amplifier, that sets an offset voltage on the output. If it is grounded, then the voltage output will be zero when the bridge is balanced. Imbalance (caused by pressure) can make the output go from 0V to +5V at the full-scale pressure with the proper choice of components and trimming. Swap the inputs to the instrumentation amplifier and you get the same thing with negative pressure.

Now, if you connect Voff to +2.5V then the output will be 2.5V when the bridge is balanced, and you can have +/-2.5V from that, so the overall span of the sensor will be the same pressure, but half plus and half minus.

This is just a general description, some precision pressure sensors use different methods such as capacitive sensing, there are other complexities involved such as adjusting for temperature drift and linearity etc. Some sensors actually have the ADC shown in the above image and digitally process the signal before converting it back into analog signals. There are many possibilities, but the above is the most likely for a relatively inexpensive industrial pressure pressure.

Answer (score 0):

If the processing is digital, then the output scaling is performed simply in software.  Some kind of digital interface (e.g. the HART protocol or local configurator) can be used to change the mode in the field.

If it's analog, then the same can be achieved by tweaking the gains and offsets of the amplifier stages using potentiometers, but this is trickier and more fiddly.